# How to export augmented types (extensions) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, prototype

I have augmented the Array prototype that mimics C# LINQ, which allows us to write complex array manipulation logic into really readable and maintainable code. It currently works really well when used in a single project like this:

ArrayExtensions.d.ts:

```
declare interface Array<T> {
    aggregate<TSource>(this: TSource[], seed: TSource, func: (accumulated: TSource, source: TSource) => TSource): TSource;
    all<T>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): boolean;
    any<T>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): boolean;
    append<T>(this: T[], value: T | T[]): T[];
    apply<T>(this: T[], action?: ((item: T) => void)): T[];
    average<T>(this: T[], callback: (item: T) => number | undefined): number | undefined;
    contains<T>(this: T[], value: T): boolean;
    count<T>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): number;
    distinct<T>(this: T[]): T[];
    empty<T>(this: T[]): boolean;
    exists<T>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): boolean;
    first<T>(this: T[], predicate?: ((item: T) => boolean)): T | undefined;
    groupBy<T>(this: T[], keyGetter: (item: T) => number): {[index: number]: T[]};
    groupBy<T>(this: T[], keyGetter: (item: T) => string): {[index: string]: T[]};
    hasOneOf(this: T[], values: T[]): boolean;
    insert<T>(this: T[], index: number, item: T): void;
    intersect<T>(this: T[], other: T[]): T[];
    last<T>(this: T[], predicate?: ((item: T) => boolean)): T | undefined;
    min<T, V>(this: T[], selector: (item: T) => V): {value: V, index: number, item: T};
    max<T, V>(this: T[], selector: (item: T) => V): {value: V, index: number, item: T};
    none(this: boolean[]): boolean;
    none<T>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): boolean;
    orderBy<T, G extends number | string | Date>(this: T[], keyGetter: (item: T) => G | undefined, order?: SortOrder): T[];
    orderByDescending<T, G extends number | string | Date>(this: T[], keyGetter: (item: T) => G | undefined): T[];
    select<T, U>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T, index: number) => U): U[];
    selectMany<TSource, TResult>(this: TSource[], selector: (item: TSource) => TResult[]): TResult[];
    sequenceEqual<T>(this: T[], other: T[]): boolean;
    single<T>(this: T[], predicate?: (item: T) => boolean): T | undefined;
    skip(this: T[], count: number): T[];
    sorted<T>(this: T[], order?: SortOrder): T[];
    sum(this: number[]): number;
    sum<T>(this: T[], callback: (item: T) => number | undefined): number;
    take<T>(this: T[], count: number): T[];
    union<T>(this: T[], other: T[]): void;
    where<T>(this: T[], predicate: (item: T) => boolean): T[];
}
```

ArrayExtensions.ts:

```
///<reference path="ArrayExtensions.d.ts" />

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'first', {
    value: function<T>(this: T[], predicate?: ((item: T) => boolean)): T | undefined {
        let index = this.firstIndex(predicate);
        return index != -1 ? this[index] : undefined;
    }
});
```

index.ts:

```
import "extensions/ArrayExtensions";
```

The problem is we need to put these extensions in our shared library that we reuse in other projects. I can't find a way to export the TypeScript declarations and make other projects use them.

I have tried to put this in the `index.ts` of the shared library:

```
export { Array } from "extensions/ArrayExtensions";
```

But it says `the module has no exported member Array.`

I have also tried to put the declarations directly into index.ts of the shared library instead of doing a reexport, but when importing it from the project that uses the library it says the module has no exported member Array. How do you export a declared interface of a project into another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are thinking in terms of importing and exporting members of a module but what you actually want is a side effecting import, just like the one you have in the index file of the project that defines the additional members. This is because your extensions modify Global values and Global types, and don't export anything.

In other words, any project needing access to these members should import them like

```
import "extensions/ArrayExtensions";
```

You have additional problems however. You have a declaration file `ArrayExtensions.d.ts` and a source file `ArrayExtensions.ts` that are located side-by-side and the one references the other via

```
///<reference path="ArrayExtensions.d.ts" />
```

The number of a potential tooling problems this introduces, especially in a shared library, but even within a single project are so numerous that I will not enumerate them here. Please, please do not do this.

Put all of the code, declaration and implementation, in the `.ts` file(s). And remove the `///<reference>`! you definitely neither want nor need anything of the sort. Anyone importing the implementation will inherently bring the corresponding type declarations into scope.

I do not know entirely how your projects reference one another, or what your build process is oh, so you may need to make a few additional changes, but what I have outlined above is important.

Comment: I have tried to move the declarations from the d.ts file into the ts file but TypeScript does not recognize the extended methods anymore. Array.prototype.first results in "first does not exist on type Array".

Comment: Can you link a repo, create a minimal reproduction, or show how your projects are linked (I.e. Separate package.json? tsconfig.json project references?)

Comment: Found out I needed declare global { } around the interface because the ArrayExtensions.ts file imports some Enums. In the project that consumes the library, I have added an  import "node_modules/utils-lib/dist/extensions/ArrayExtensions". TypeScript successfully recognizes the extension methods in the project, however when compiling WebPack throws that it can't resolve "node_modules/utils-lib/dist/extensions/ArrayExtensions". Do you have any idea? I should probably tell webpack to ignore these imports since only the side-effect is needed?

Comment: I had a feeling I should have mentioned declare global. No, webpack absolutely has to include that code because it contains the implementation of those methods. I assume you're using the one file Approach. Your import should not include the full path to a dependency like that. It should be `import "utils-lib/dist/extensions/ArrayExtensions"` and that directory should contain the compiled JavaScript file and compiled declaration file unless you're using custom loader config compile code in node modules. Perhaps update your question with a little more information and show what's in dist

Comment: Yes I use the one file approach you suggested. I've dug and problem I have is a bit out of the scope of my initial question. In that shared library we also have Vue components, which requires us to use WebPack to compile the lib instead of tsc, which produces a single index.js file into /dist instead of individual js files. As you pointed, in the project that consumes the library, WebPack tries to load ArrayExtensions.js which does not exists, and it should not need to because the implementations are already loaded from the index.js file when other things from the shared library are imported

Comment: I have compiled ArrayExtensions to a single ArrayExtensions.js using tsc and put it into dist/extensions. Now the project compiles fine, but produces a "Cannot redefine property" error at runtime, because WebPack bundled the implementation twice (the one in index.js and the one in ArrayExtensions.js). So I  need to find a way to tell WebPack to ignore that import or maybe I will split the shared library.

Comment: I don't know if you can help me further, but many thanks anyway, greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your shared library's index references the array methods, you should just import the library like `import "utils-lib";` to get any side effects like the additional array methods. Webpack shouldn't be bundling the file twice even so. It sounds like there's an issue with your config. That said, could that augments globals like `Array` should be guarded to ensure the additional member doesn't already exist when the code runs.