# Array.at() method missing from typescript array type

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

With:

```
const myArray = [0,4,2];
myArray.at(-1);
```

I get the following error under `.at`

> Property 'at' does not exist on type 'number[]'.ts (2339)

What's going on here why doesn't `Array.at()` work? Do I have to set some sort of browserlist value to let TS know that I want to be able to use this (recently spec'd) feature?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}
```

Comment: You have to use a proper value of `lib`. Try `"esnext"`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky - It's not even in the `ESNext` target yet. Presumably it will be very soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like even specifying `"lib": "esnext"` doesn't do it ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gRgAwF0DcAoUSWAIyXgDo4oAKAWjQEocg)).

**Temporarily**, you can do it manually by using your own definitions file to augment the array interface (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62987407/how-to-export-augmented-types-extensions-in-typescript)):¹

```teypscript
declare interface Array<T> {
   at(index: number): T | undefined;
}
```

That enables it for now ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCCCMMUAngDwAqAfPAN4BQ8jUqAFCqAB4Bc8yArgFsARhgCUPcvAA+8PslCYUIYAG46AXzpgA9sgDOqeFHgBeeAG0AjAAYAump37DQ00YB0zFgFpLolUA)).

In very short order (edit: looks like ***very*** short order, see [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71224657/157247)), you should be able to remove that once TypeScript adds it to the `ESNext` target (and then to the `ES2022` target once the spec is officially adopted in June; the proposal is Stage 4 so it will be in the next snapshot).

---

¹ There's an argument for `index?: number` rather than `index: number`, since the spec explicitly handles the case where converting the argument to number results in `NaN` by saying to use `0` (`at` uses [ToIntegerOrInfinity](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tointegerorinfinity) on the argument, which does the substitution). So per spec, `[10].at()` returns `10`. But hopefully they use the stricter definition of it.

Answer (score 9):

[The `Array.prototype.at()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) is part of `ES2022`, which didn't quite make it into TypeScript 4.5.  It is part of TypeScript 4.6, so once that is officially released (which, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#46858](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46858) should be *today*, 2022-02-22,) you can just set your target to `ES2022` or `ESNext`:

```
const myArray = [0,4,2]
myArray.at(-1); // okay
```

[Playground link using TS4.6.1-RC](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.6.1-rc&ssl=2&ssc=24&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEwLwwNoAMANACxEBMAugLABQiqGCAdOlABQC0AjAJQDcMAPRCYIANaYgA)